# Cant create foreign key in mysql innodb table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have the following 3 tables bellow.
When I want to create this foreign key:

```
 alter table `template_parts_data` add constraint template_parts_data_template_row_id_foreign foreign key (`template_row_id`) references `template_rows` (`id`)
```

I get his error:
`General error: 1005 Can't create table email_template.#sql-1234_1a0 (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")`

```
CREATE TABLE `templates` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `templates_rows` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `template_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `template_part_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `templates_rows_template_id_foreign` (`template_id`),
 KEY `templates_rows_template_part_id_foreign` (`template_part_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `templates_rows_template_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`template_id`) REFERENCES `templates` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `templates_rows_template_part_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`template_part_id`) REFERENCES `template_parts` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `template_parts` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `html` longtext NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `template_parts_data` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `data_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `data_val` longtext NOT NULL,
 `template_row_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: I received this error when the one field was unsigned and the other field was signed. But from the syntax it looks like your's are both unsigned so my comment might not help you but might help others.

Answer (score 0):

In the line that starts the creation of the table 'template_parts_data', why do you have the name of the table before the create.  I am not familiar with the syntax you are using, but this seems wrong and would cause unpredictable error codes.

Comment: This is because of the copy paste from phpmyadmin, removed